# ANTLR: Lexer rule accepting strictly one letter, and a token of multiple chars, instead of just one (Java)

Tags: java, antlr, token, chars

I've written the below grammar for ANTLR parser and lexer for building trees for logical formulae and had a couple of questions if someone could help:

```
class AntlrFormulaParser extends Parser;

options {
    buildAST = true;
}

biconexpr : impexpr (BICONDITIONAL^ impexpr)*;

impexpr : orexpr (IMPLICATION^ orexpr)*;

orexpr : andexpr (DISJUNCTION^ andexpr)*;

andexpr : notexpr (CONJUNCTION^ notexpr)*;

notexpr : (NEGATION^)? formula;

formula 
    : atom
    | LEFT_PAREN! biconexpr RIGHT_PAREN!
    ;

atom
    : CHAR
    | TRUTH
    | FALSITY
    ;


class AntlrFormulaLexer extends Lexer;

// Atoms
CHAR: 'a'..'z';
TRUTH: ('\u22A4' | 'T');
FALSITY: ('\u22A5' | 'F');

// Grouping
LEFT_PAREN: '(';
RIGHT_PAREN: ')';
NEGATION: ('\u00AC' | '~' | '!');
CONJUNCTION: ('\u2227' | '&' | '^');
DISJUNCTION: ('\u2228' | '|' | 'V');
IMPLICATION: ('\u2192' | "->");
BICONDITIONAL: ('\u2194' | "<->");

WHITESPACE : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n') { $setType(Token.SKIP); };
```

The tree grammar:

```
tree grammar AntlrFormulaTreeParser;

options {
    tokenVocab=AntlrFormula;
    ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}

expr returns [Formula f]
    : ^(BICONDITIONAL f1=expr f2=expr) {
        $f = new Biconditional(f1, f2);
    }
    | ^(IMPLICATION f1=expr f2=expr) {
        $f = new Implication(f1, f2);
    }
    | ^(DISJUNCTION f1=expr f2=expr) {
        $f = new Disjunction(f1, f2);
    }
    | ^(CONJUNCTION f1=expr f2=expr) {
        $f = new Conjunction(f1, f2);
    }
    | ^(NEGATION f1=expr) {
        $f = new Negation(f1);
    }
    | CHAR {
        $f = new Atom($CHAR.getText());
    }
    | TRUTH {
        $f = Atom.TRUTH;
    }
    | FALSITY {
        $f = Atom.FALSITY;
    }
    ;
```

The problems I'm having with the above grammar are these:

1. The tokens, IMPLICATION and BICONDITIONAL, in the java code for AntlrFormulaLexer only seem to be checking for their respective first character (i.e. '-' and '<') to match the token, instead of the whole string, as specified in the grammar.
2. When testing the java code for AntlrFormulaParser, if I pass a string such as "~ab", it returns a tree of "(~ a)" (and a string "ab&c" returns just "a"), when it should really be returning an error/exception, since an atom can only have one letter according to the above grammar. It doesn't give any error/exception at all with these sample strings.

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me solve these couple of problems. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the following definitions as:

```
IMPLICATION: ('\u2192' | '->');
BICONDITIONAL: ('\u2194' | '<->');
```

note "->" vs '->'

And to solve the error issue:

```
formula 
    : (
         atom
       | LEFT_PAREN! biconexpr RIGHT_PAREN! 
      ) EOF
    ;
```

from here:
http://www.antlr.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4554943

Fixed grammar to compile against antlr 3.3 (save as AntlrFormula.g):

```
grammar AntlrFormula;

options {
    output = AST; 
}


program : formula ;

formula : atom | LEFT_PAREN! biconexpr RIGHT_PAREN! ;

biconexpr : impexpr (BICONDITIONAL^ impexpr)*;

impexpr : orexpr (IMPLICATION^ orexpr)*;

orexpr : andexpr (DISJUNCTION^ andexpr)*;

andexpr : notexpr (CONJUNCTION^ notexpr)*;

notexpr : (NEGATION^)? formula;


atom
    : CHAR
    | TRUTH
    | FALSITY
    ;


// Atoms
CHAR: 'a'..'z';
TRUTH: ('\u22A4' | 'T');
FALSITY: ('\u22A5' | 'F');

// Grouping
LEFT_PAREN: '(';
RIGHT_PAREN: ')';
NEGATION: ('\u00AC' | '~' | '!');
CONJUNCTION: ('\u2227' | '&' | '^');
DISJUNCTION: ('\u2228' | '|' | 'V');
IMPLICATION: ('\u2192' | '->');
BICONDITIONAL: ('\u2194' | '<->');

WHITESPACE : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n') { $channel = HIDDEN; };
```

Link to antlr 3.3 binary: http://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-3.3-complete.jar

you will need to try to match the program rule in order to match the complete file.

testable with this class:

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AntlrFormulaLexer lexer = new AntlrFormulaLexer(new ANTLRStringStream("(~ab)"));
        AntlrFormulaParser p = new AntlrFormulaParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));

        try {
            p.program();
            if ( p.failed() || p.getNumberOfSyntaxErrors() != 0) {
                System.out.println("failed");
            }
        } catch (RecognitionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error with the above definitions:       

error: Token stream error reading grammar(s):
Formula.g:41:28: expecting ''', found '>'
TokenStreamException: expecting ''', found '>'

I think I tried your definitions initially, but got the error and decided to switch to double quotes.

Comment: strange .. in their samples they allow this:  ASSERT :   'assert' ;. See the java.g grammer from their site.

Comment: same for closure grammar. https://github.com/laurentpetit/ccw/blob/master/clojure-antlr-grammar/src/Clojure.g. What antlr version do you use ?

Comment: I'm using the latest version, v3.3, I think.

Comment: i doubt it :). I just compiled your sample with 3.3 and failed a lot :). I'll post a proper file (compilable with 3.3) and a link to antlr 3.3 distribution and i'll ask you to test it.

Comment: Actually, the original IMPLICATION and BICONDITIONAL definitions do seem to be working. Using my original definitions, it only parses when there's a "->" or "<->", resp.

Comment: It that's the case then you should just add a rule like program : formula EOF; and match the program rule. This will give you an error when the input does not match completely.

Comment: I just realised I was using antlr.Tool, when I should really have been using org.antlr.Tool. Anyway, after I realised this, I tried running the parser code generated from your grammar, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to test it, i.e. what code to write to get the CommonTree from an input string. Do you think you could help me out with that? Thanks :)

Comment: I added some testing code. You should probably download and try the antlrworks tool. It's legendary :).

Comment: Ah, awesome. Everything seems to be working as expected now. I just have a last couple of favours to ask of you. One, do you know how I could disable defaultErrorHandlers in ANTLR 3? And, second, I wrote a tree parser earlier as well, would you mind looking at it and seeing if it'll work with ANTLR 3.3 (I've added it at the bottom of the code in my original question) and if not, could you possibly give me an updated version, so that it will work?

Comment: I'll keep the tool in mind, for the next time I have to use ANTLR (I probably won't have the opportunity to use it again anytime soon). Anyway, thanks a lot for your help. I really really appreciate it :)

Comment: Hi, I've been trying to get the tree grammar to work, but I can't seem to make it work. Would you mind looking at the tree grammar in my original post and possibly seeing what's wrong with it? Thank you :)

Comment: It's okay. It definitely works. I just had to run antlr on it separately.